# Pass a dictionary to Application.OnTime

Tags: vba, dictionary, ontime

I would like to pass a Scripting.Dictionary object to Application.OnTime.
The problem is that I keep getting a 'Compile error : Argument not optional'.

The structure of the code is the following :

```
Public Sub mainSub()

    Dim orderBookIndex As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim contractIndex As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Call computeStuff(0, orderBookIndex, contractIndex)

End Sub
```

mainSub calls computeStuff, then computeStuff calls 'callLive' to launch itself each second after having been incremented.

```
Public Sub computeStuff(index As Integer, Optional orderBookIndex As Scripting.Dictionary, Optional contractIndex As Scripting.Dictionary)

    ' Do stuff

    If index = 0 Then
        Set orderBookIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Set contractIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
    End If

    If index = 1 Then

       Set orderBookIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
       Set contractIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary

       orderBookIndex.add "a", "b" ' add random stuff

       contractIndex.add "c", "d" ' add random stuff

    End If

    Call callLive(index, orderBookIndex, contractIndex)

End Sub
```

Then callLive is called and refuses to compile :

```
Public Sub callLive(index As Integer, Optional orderBookIndex As Scripting.Dictionary, Optional contractIndex As Scripting.Dictionary)

    Dim SchTime As Double

    SchTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    index = index + 1
    Application.OnTime SchTime, "'computeStuff """ & index & """ ,""" & orderBookIndex & """ ,""" & contractIndex & """'", , False

End Sub
```

Any help or guidance to achieve this task (or solve this issue) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is usually recommended to keep global variables to minimum use, but, why not try it: make the dictionary objects 'orderBookIndex' and `contractIndex' global variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try having the orderBookIndex and contractIndex as global variables instead like below and see if that works for you:

```
Public orderBookIndex As Scripting.Dictionary
Public contractIndex As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Sub mainSub()

Set orderBookIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set contractIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary

Call computeStuff(0, orderBookIndex, contractIndex)

End Sub
Public Sub computeStuff(index As Integer, Optional orderBookIndex As Scripting.Dictionary, Optional contractIndex As Scripting.Dictionary)

' Do stuff

If index = 0 Then
    Set orderBookIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set contractIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
End If

If index = 1 Then

   Set orderBookIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary
   Set contractIndex = New Scripting.Dictionary

   orderBookIndex.Add "a", "b" ' add random stuff

   contractIndex.Add "c", "d" ' add random stuff

End If

Call callLive(index, orderBookIndex, contractIndex)

End Sub

Public Sub callLive(index As Integer, orderBookIndex As Scripting.Dictionary, contractIndex As Scripting.Dictionary)

Dim SchTime As Double

SchTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
index = index + 1
Application.OnTime SchTime, "'computeStuff " & index & " , orderBookIndex, contractIndex'"

End Sub
```